# How do you correctly implement Scipy's FFT procedures to produce a low-pass filter - image processing

Tags: python, scipy, fourier-transform, image-processing

I'm following this low-pass filter example in the text "Image Operators: Image Processing in Python 1st Edition" by Jason M. Kinser, but can't seem to duplicate their results.

The text's code:

```
import imageio
import scipy.fftpack as ft
import mgcreate as mgc

amg = imageio.imread('data/reschartsmall.png', as_gray=True)
bmg = 1 - amg/amg.max()
cmg = ft.fftshift(ft.fft2(bmg))
V,H = cmg.shape
circ = mgc.Circle((V,H), (V/2,H/2), 10)
dmg = ft.ifft2(ft.fftshift(circ*cmg))
imageio.imsave('figure.png', -dmg.real)
```

where the Circle function is given by

```
# mgcreate.py
def Circle(size, loc, rad):
    b1,b2 = np.indices(size)
    b1,b2 = b1-loc[0], b2-loc[1]
    mask = b1*b1 + b2*b2
    mask = (mask <= rad*rad).astype(int)
    return mask
```

The following is the original image and the final image after the low-pass filter code above is applied:

[image]

I load in the image from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joefoxva1/CDS468/master/Lectures10_11_12/USAF1951w.jpg
but otherwise, I'm using the same code. This is the image I'm producing:

[image]

My image appears to be inverted (apparently fixed by saving the image as dmg.real instead of -dmg.real) and nonuniform (the two FFT procedures together are creating a band in the center of the image). I don't understand why I'm observing different behavior of the same code. My guesses were that maybe the Scipy fftpack functions have changed since the publishing of the text or that the image I'm importing isn't the same somehow (doesn't seem likely, the code produces similar behavior with other images).

Comment: How does the image you start from look like?

Comment: This is the image that I start with: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joefoxva1/CDS468/master/Lectures10_11_12/USAF1951w.jpg and then I load it in as gray as the example does.

Comment: What I meant is: if you output the picture as you loaded it, does it also have the inverted brightness scheme?